# Python socket returns no exception and resumes fine even though there is no host listening

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("27.0.0.1", 14345))
```

When you run this, there is no exception, nothing, it just resumes fine, even though there is nothing listening on the other end.

Edit: Found the reason why is this happening. A VPN connection, but there should still be nothing listening, and also if I setup a connection listening, it connects to that fine, but if there is nothing, it doesn't raise any exception.
It worked as expected when I turned the VPN off.

Comment: There has to be something else going on. Assuming you've omitted `import socket`, did you run these exact 3 lines or is this part of other code? Running these 3 lines, my machine times out in 132 seconds.

Comment: I didn't omit import socket. The code is literally this with an import scoket at the top, executed from pycharm. And I get "Process finished with exit code 0". Nothing else.

Comment: And what about if you add: ‘print(‘Done’)’ on the end?

Comment: Um, looking at the two lines of code posted, there is no `import socket`. Sometimes people summarize code without running it. And sometimes you'll find that the real code sets a socket to nonblocking before connect. That's why I asked.

Comment: https://replit.com/@JoranBeasley/HorizontalRotatingVendors#main.py   unable to reproduce ... just hangs for a loooong time

Comment: Well, I kinda assumed that code be run with an import socket, so I didn't include it in this post, but edited. I tried in CMD too, and it still gives no exception. Added "print("done")" too, and it prints fine. Weird, something must be wrong on my end.

Comment: Hmmm, I found the source of the issue, a VPN connection, it gives an exception after I turned the VPN off, but this is still weird.

Comment: I can't reproduce with this code. Mine hangs trying to connect. However, if I change the address to: `"127.0.0.1"`, then I get `ConnectionRefusedError`.

Comment: Somehow the VPN messed something up. Even though there should still have been no listening connection (this is the loopback interface, and also if there is something listening, it connects to that).

Comment: @Hormoz - 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. This is in the 27.0.0.0/22 domain which is registered to amazon in Tokyo.

Comment: ......Thanks for pointing that out lol. This no longer seems as weird. This issue is solved I guess. Except the part that it connected fine when I listened on it.